# Simple Objective-C calculator program printing continuously

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing my first real objective C program and it's to make a very simple calculator like in the book Programming in Objective-C 2.0 by Stephen Kochan.

Anyway, whenever I run the program it just continually prints the same thing over and over again, not giving me the option to type anything else.  The code is below, and if anyone could help I think the problem is somewhere between the while loop and the switch function.  Thank you in advance!

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Calculator : NSObject {
    double number, accumulator;
    char operator;
}

    -(void) add: (double) n;
    -(void) subtract: (double) n;
    -(void) multiply: (double) n;
    -(void) divide: (double) n;


@end

@implementation Calculator

-(void) add: (double) n {
    accumulator += n;
    NSLog(@"%fl", accumulator);
}

-(void) subtract: (double) n {
    accumulator -= n;
    NSLog(@"%fl", accumulator);
}

-(void) multiply: (double) n {
    accumulator *= n;
    NSLog(@"%fl", accumulator);
}

-(void) divide: (double) n {
    if (n == 0)
        NSLog(@"Error! You can't divide by 0!");
    else
        accumulator /= n;
        NSLog(@"%fl", accumulator);

}

@end






int main(int argc, const char * argv[])

{ 

    @autoreleasepool {
        double number, accumulator;
        char operator;

        Calculator *myCalc = [[Calculator alloc] init];

        NSLog(@"Begin calculations by typing a number then S");
        scanf("%lf, %c", &accumulator, &operator);

        while (operator != 'E') {
            NSLog(@"%lf", accumulator);
            NSLog(@"What would you like to do next?");
            scanf("%lf, %c", &number, &operator);

            switch (operator) {
                case '+':
                    [myCalc add: number];
                    break;

                case '-':
                    [myCalc subtract: number];
                    break;

                case '*':
                    [myCalc multiply: number];
                    break;

                case '/':
                    [myCalc divide: number];
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }



            }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try putting these at the end of your while:  NSLog(@"What would you like to do next?");
            scanf("%lf, %c", &number, &operator); This will cause the program to stop once it gets to these instead of going constantly

Comment: I don't know how I missed that!! But unfortunately, it's still running continuously and I don't know why...

Comment: @AshleyElisabethStallings Uh, so I don't know where my previous comment is gone, but let me repeat it: I suggest you learn C well before trying to start out with Objective-C (and this includes knowledge about the C standard library as well, not only the language), else you'll get into trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

**In short: don't use `scanf()`. It doesn't work how you think it does.**

I'm already tried explaining what's wrong, but basically it doesn't like newlines and stuff and it's pedantic. Search SO for [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scanf+doesn%27t+work). The easy solution is to replace `scanf()` with something actually useful, such as

```
char buf[0x100];
char *end;

fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
accumulator = strtod(buf, &end);
while (isspace(*end))
    end++;

operator = *end;
```

Also, your calculator logic is flawed. The `myCalc` object doesn't share the identically named `accumulator` variable with the `main()` function. Your program basically doesn't take into account the first number entered. Also, I don't see what purpose the "type 'S'" part serves, there's absolutely no check for entering "S" in the code, only "E" for end.

---

On a side note: we're in C (basically), but it's still not a good idea to use C++ keywords as identifiers. Let `new` and `operator` be reserved. Call that variable `op`.

Also, as a design improvement, you can abstract away the big `switch` statement **into** the calculator class, and that way you could write something like `[myCalc performOp:'+' withNumber:number];` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to try all this out so hopefully it'll work!
And I agree the "S" doesn't really make sense, but I'm just working through a suggested problem from this book and that's how it wanted me to do it. Haha but thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` is generally a bad function to use.  It's generally better to read an input line into a string and then use `sscanf` (or some other parser) on the string.

However, the fix in this case is simple.  `scanf` returns the number of input items successfully assigned.  You expect two.  If there's an error, or end-of-file is reached, it will return less than two.  Thus:

```
        int rc = scanf("%lf, %c", &number, &operator);
        if (rc < 2) {
            break;
        }
```